# What is the best book to learn how to make themes for wordpress?

Tags: theme-development, themes

Do you any good book or video tutorials that easily explain how can I make my own theme for Wordpress? and how to change the structure of the content?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

I would start with the Codex:

1. [WordPress Codex: Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

These two books are still current enough to remain great resources:

1. [Smashing WordPress Themes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047066990X), Thord Daniel Hedengren
2. [Build Your Own Wicked WordPress Themes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0980455294), Alan Cole, Jeffrey Way, et al

These also have Theme applicability:

1. [Digging Into WordPress](http://digwp.com/book/), Chris Coyier, Jeff Starr
2. [Professional WordPress Plugin Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470916222), Brad Williams et al
3. [Professional WordPress](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470560541), Brad Williams et al
4. [WordPress Bible](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470568135), Aaron Brazell

Most of the rest are either too general, or too outdated.

**EDIT**

Forgot to add Digging Into WordPress!